# Why are the $r$ and $\theta$ unit vectors defined as such?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I refer to this derivation of the gradient in polar coordinates: http://www.math.jhu.edu/~js/Math202/polar.grad.chain.pdf

I can understand all parts except why the unit gradient $$\hat{e_r}=\langle\cos\theta,\sin\theta\rangle$$
$$\hat{e_\theta}=\langle-\sin\theta,\cos\theta\rangle$$

are defined as such?

I can hazard a guess due to $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$, so when $r=1$, that possibly leads to $\hat{e_r}$?
And $\hat{e_\theta}$ has to be orthogonal, but why not $\langle \sin\theta, -\cos\theta\rangle$?

Any other explanation?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Draw a plot. The answer is obvious then. You want it in the direction of increasing $\theta$.

Comment: Is there any diagram online where I can refer to?

Comment: For goodness sake, draw your own!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guesses are correct. Just note that $\hat e_\theta$ increases in the anticlockwise direction. So it won't be like you have guessed, rather it will be what is given in the pdf.

Answer (score 1):

For a point $\mathbf{x}(r,\theta) = (x(r,\theta),y(r,\theta))$, $\hat{e_r}$ is defined as a length 1 vector in the direction of $\frac{\partial \mathbf{x}}{\partial r}$, and similarly for $\hat{e_\theta}$. Hence they represent the so-called 'infinitesimal' direction of change when $r$ or $\theta$ increases.