# Why the unitary vectors in polar coordinates are defined as such?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I read in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1867401/why-are-the-r-and-theta-unit-vectors-defined-as-such) post that says $\mathbf{e_r}$ and $\mathbf{e_\theta}$ are defined in the direction in which the coordinates increases.
But, for example, in cartesian coordinates you can do this:
$$
\mathbf v = a\mathbf i + b\mathbf j
$$
where $a$, $b$, represent the coordinates in the $x$ and $y$ axes respectively.
So you could guess that in polar coordinates:
$$
\mathbf v = r\mathbf{e_r} + \theta\mathbf{e_\theta}
$$
where, $r$ is the radius (or distance to the origin) and $\theta$ is the angle with the horizontal axes. But as you might know, this do not work.

I suppose this only works in cartesians coordinates because it is an "exceptional case". But then, why are the basis defined as this:
$$
\mathbf{e_r} = (\cos{\theta}, \sin{\theta}) \\
\mathbf{e_\theta} = (-\sin{\theta}, \cos{\theta})
$$
It loses some intuitive meaning (contrary to cartesian coordinates). Why are they defined like so?

Comment: It seems convenient to have one unit vector which points in the direction of increasing $r$ (with $\theta$ held fixed) and another unit vector which points in the direction of increasing $\theta$ (with $r$ held fixed).

Comment: Don't the vectors $\hat i$ and $\hat j$ also point in the directions that $x$ and $y$ increase, respectively?

Comment: The vectors $\mathbf e_r$ and $\mathbf e_\theta$ have meaning only *after* you have decided on a particular point of the plane (not the origin) where they are to be defined. A fortiori, you cannot use the vectors as a basis for position vectors in the plane. They are mostly useful as "velocity" vectors of some sort. Does [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3952005/139123) help?

Comment: @DavidK The position vector in polar coordinates is given by $r\hat r$. We start with that when we derive the rotational dynamics equations in the plane.

Comment: @JohnDouma If all you tell me about a point is that it is at $3\hat\imath$, I know exactly where in the plane it is. If you tell me it is at $3\hat r,$ I might infer that it is on the circle of radius $3$ around the origin, but I have no idea *which* point on the circle. You have to tell me *which* $\hat r$ you had in mind. But that means $\hat r$ is just an ordinary unit vector for that purpose, not a basis vector. There is no predetermined basis vector $\hat r$ by which the position of any point in the plane can be described.

Comment: If $\hat r$ were actually a basis vector for position in the plane, then you would expect that together with the orthogonal basis vector $\hat\theta$ and coefficients for both you could name any point on the plane, and add two position vectors by adding coefficients to derive a third position vector. But you can't.

Comment: @DavidK The angle is encoded in the definition of $\hat r$. The unit vector depends on $\theta$. I make no claim about basis vectors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139153/discussion-between-david-k-and-john-douma).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let consider a position vector in cartesian coordinates

$$P(t) = x(t) \mathbf i+y(t) \mathbf j$$

then consider its velocity in cartesian coordinates

$$v(t) = \dot P(t) = \dot x(t) \mathbf i+\dot y(t) \mathbf j$$

In polar coordinates, the position vector is

$$P(t) = r(t)\cos \left(\theta(t)\right) \mathbf i+r(t)\sin\left(\theta(t)\right) \mathbf j$$

and its velocity is

$$v(t) = \dot P(t) = 
\left[\dot r(t) \cos\left(\theta(t)\right)-r(t)\dot \theta(t)\sin\left(\theta(t)\right)\right] \mathbf i
+\left[\dot r(t) \sin\left(\theta(t)\right)+r(t)\dot \theta(t)\cos\left(\theta(t)\right)\right] \mathbf j=$$

$$=\dot r(t)\left[\cos\left(\theta(t)\right)\mathbf i+\sin\left(\theta(t)\right)\mathbf j\right]+r(t)\dot \theta(t)\left[-\sin\left(\theta(t)\right)\mathbf i+\cos\left(\theta(t)\right)\mathbf j\right]=$$

$$=\dot r(t)\mathbf{e_r}+r(t)\dot \theta(t)\mathbf{e_\theta}$$

with

- $\mathbf{e_r} = \left[\cos\left(\theta(t)\right), \sin\left(\theta(t)\right)\right]$ which is parallel to $r(t)$
- $\mathbf{e_\theta} =   \left[-\sin\left(\theta(t)\right), \cos\left(\theta(t)\right)\right]$ which is orthogonal to $r(t)$

and as we can see such unit vectors are really useful to describe derivatives or gradients in polar coordinates.

---

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The position vector in polar coordinates is $\vec r=r\hat r$ where $r$ is the distance from the origin along the direction specified by the unit vector $\hat r$. We don't use $\hat\theta$ for the position because it is not needed.

The unit vector $\hat\theta$ comes into play when we derive the velocity and acceleration because $$\frac{d\hat r}{d\theta}=\hat\theta$$ and $$\frac{d\hat\theta}{d\theta}=-\hat r$$

which are easily verified by looking at the definitions of these unit vectors.

Answer (score 0):

$
\newcommand\PD[2]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}
\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}
$

#### Point Functions and Coordinate Functions

A system of coordinates $x^1, x^2$ can be specified in two ways:

1. As a function $\mathbf p(x^1, x^2)$ taking *coordinates to points*. We will call this the *point function* of a coordinate system.
2. As functions $X^1(\mathbf q), X^2(\mathbf q)$ taking *points to coordinates*. We will call these the *coordinate functions* of a coordinate system.

These are inverses of each other, in that we want the following to be true:
$$
  \mathbf p(X^1(\mathbf q), X^2(\mathbf q)) = \mathbf q,
\tag{1}
$$$$
  X^1(\mathbf p(x^1, x^2)) = x^1,\quad X^2(\mathbf p(x^2, x^2)) = x^2.
\tag{2}
$$
In addition to Cartesian and polar coordinates,
for the sake of example we will also consider a simple
*non-orthogonal* coordinate system.
We have
$$
  \mathbf p_{xy}(x, y) = x\mathbf i + y\mathbf j,
\tag{Cartesian}
$$$$
  \mathbf p_{r\theta}(r,\theta) = r(\cos\theta)\mathbf i + r(\sin\theta)\mathbf j,
\tag{Polar}
$$$$
  \mathbf p_{uv}(u, v) = (u^3 + v)\mathbf i + v\mathbf j,
\tag{NonOrtho}
$$
and
$$
  X(\mathbf q) = \mathbf q\cdot\mathbf i,\quad
  Y(\mathbf q) = \mathbf q\cdot\mathbf j,
\tag{Cartesian}
$$$$
  R(\mathbf q) = |\mathbf q|,\quad
  \cos\Theta(\mathbf q) = \frac{\mathbf q\cdot\mathbf i}{|\mathbf q|},
\tag{Polar}
$$$$
  \mathbf U(\mathbf q) = \sqrt[3]{\mathbf q\cdot(\mathbf i - \mathbf j)},\quad
  \mathbf V(\mathbf q) = \mathbf q\cdot\mathbf j.
\tag{NonOrthog}
$$

Equations (1) and (2) allow us to turn any function on points $f(\mathbf q)$
into a function on coordinates:
$$
  f(\mathbf p(x^1, x^2))
$$
and any function on coordinates $g(x^1, x^2)$ into a function on points:
$$
  g(X^1(\mathbf q), X^2(\mathbf q)).
$$
We tend to prefer functions on points,
since that is more geometrically meaningful,
but I will freely switch between both perspectives.

#### Basis from Coordinates

Conceptually, vectors are *differences* or *changes* in points;
if you have two points $\mathbf q_1, \mathbf q_2 \in \R^2$,
then $\mathbf q_1 - \mathbf q_2$ is exactly the vector
pointing from $\mathbf q_2$ to $\mathbf q_1$.
Given a coordinate function $\mathbf p(x^1, x^2)$,
this idea motivates the definition of the *vector basis*
associated to the coordinate system $x^1, x^2$
as the "infinitesimal change" between points when $x^1$ and $x^2$ vary:
$$
  \mathbf e_1 = \PD{\mathbf p}{x^1},\quad \mathbf e_2 = \PD{\mathbf p}{x^2}.
$$
For example we may compute
$$
  \mathbf e_x = \mathbf i,\quad
  \mathbf e_y = \mathbf j,
\tag{Cartesian}
$$$$
  \mathbf e_r = (\cos\theta)\mathbf i + (\sin\theta)\mathbf j,\quad
  \mathbf e_\theta = -r(\sin\theta)\mathbf i + r(\cos\theta)\mathbf j,
\tag{Polar}
$$$$
  \mathbf e_u = 3u^2\mathbf i,\quad
  \mathbf e_v = \mathbf i + \mathbf j.
\tag{NonOrtho}
$$
Note that $\mathbf e_r$ and $\mathbf e_\theta$ are orthogonal,
and $\mathbf e_u$ and $\mathbf e_v$ are *not* orthogonal.
Though I've left it implicit,
it's important to note here that $\mathbf e_1$ and $\mathbf e_2$
are functions of $x^1, x^2$ and hence also functions on points;
that is to say that we've actually assigned a basis to each point,
and each such basis may be and usually is distinct from those at other points.

#### Reciprocal Basis

For any vector basis $\mathbf e_1, \mathbf e_3$,
there is a unique *reciprocal basis* $\mathbf e^1, \mathbf e^2$ such that
$$
  \mathbf e^1\cdot\mathbf e_1 = \mathbf e^2\cdot\mathbf e_2 = 1,\quad
  \mathbf e^1\cdot\mathbf e_2 = \mathbf e^2\cdot\mathbf e_1 = 0.
\tag{3}
$$
If $\mathbf e_1, \mathbf e_2$ are implicitly functions (of points or coordinates),
then the reciprocal basis is as well.
We may in fact compute them by taking the gradient
of the coordinate functions:
$$
  \mathbf e^1 = \nabla_{\mathbf q}X^1(\mathbf q),\quad
  \mathbf e^2 = \nabla_{\mathbf q}X^2(\mathbf q).
$$
In fact, this is in a sense a *definition* of the gradient,
but I will not get into that here.
Returning to our examples, we can compute
$$
  \mathbf e^x = \mathbf i,\quad
  \mathbf e^y = \mathbf j,
\tag{Cartesian}
$$$$
  \mathbf e^r = \frac{\mathbf q}{|\mathbf q|} = \mathbf e_r,\quad
  \mathbf e^\theta = \frac1{|\mathbf q|^2}\mathbf e_\theta
\tag{Polar}
$$$$
  \mathbf e^u = \frac{\mathbf i-\mathbf j}{3[U(\mathbf q)]^2},\quad
  \mathbf e^v = \mathbf j.
\tag{NonOrthog}
$$
$e^\theta$ is easiest to compute using the definition (3),
rather than trying to take a gradient.

#### Vector "Coordinates"

The definition (3) of the reciprocal vectors
immediately gives us for any vector $\mathbf v$
$$
  \mathbf v
     = (\mathbf e^1\cdot\mathbf v)\mathbf e_1 + (\mathbf e^2\cdot\mathbf v)\mathbf e_2
     = (\mathbf e_1\cdot\mathbf v)\mathbf e^1 + (\mathbf e_2\cdot\mathbf v)\mathbf e^2.
$$
Say that $\mathbf v$ is *expanded at the point $\mathbf q$*
if we evaluate the above implicit functions at the point $\mathbf q$.
This gives the expansion of a vector in the corresponding basis,
what might be called the "coordinates" of the vector,
but these "coordinates" are **not** the same thing
as the *point* coordinates of our coordinate system.
We will instead call them the *component magnitudes* of a vector.
In our examples, we make the implicit functional dependences explicit,
consider the specific case where $\mathbf v$
is thought of as a *position vector*,
and expand the vector $\mathbf v$ at the point it represents:
$$
  \mathbf e^x(\mathbf v)\cdot\mathbf v = X(\mathbf v),\quad
  \mathbf e^y(\mathbf v)\cdot\mathbf v = Y(\mathbf v),
\tag{Cartesian}
$$$$
  \mathbf e^r(\mathbf v)\cdot\mathbf v = R(\mathbf v),\quad
  \mathbf e^\theta(\mathbf v)\cdot\mathbf v = 0,
\tag{Polar}
$$$$
  \mathbf e^u(\mathbf v)\cdot\mathbf v = \frac13U(\mathbf v),\quad
  \mathbf e^v(\mathbf v)\cdot\mathbf v = V(\mathbf v),
\tag{NonOrthog}
$$
yielding
$$
  \mathbf v = X(\mathbf v)\mathbf e_x(\mathbf v) + Y(\mathbf v)\mathbf e_y(\mathbf v),
\tag{Cartesian}
$$$$
  \mathbf v = R(\mathbf v)\mathbf e_r(\mathbf v),
\tag{Polar}
$$$$
  \mathbf v = \frac13U(\mathbf v)\mathbf e_u(\mathbf v) + V(\mathbf v)\mathbf e_v.
\tag{NonOrthog}
$$

Component magnitudes are not coordinates,
even if they may be coincidentally for some coordinate systems.
Even then, question of component magnitudes coinciding with coordinates
only makes sense for *position vectors expanded around the point they represent*;
this is a very particular situation.
The moral should be that **vectors and points are distinct** as geometric entities;
really, it is a side-effect of modeling flat space with a vector space
that points may be identified with vectors.
Another way to say this is that, considered as a manifold,
the tangent space of e.g. $\R^2$ at a point is just $\R^2$;
this should be considered a very special case.